# Ruby program exits too soon, data being overwritten

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Ruby program to simulate a course management system. As my program currently stands, when the user first loads the program, they are presented with a menu. I am currently just working on the first option in the menu- which is to add a module to a scheme.

Working through this step by step, when the user selects this option from the menu, they are asked to enter a scheme name, which is saved as the key in a hash called 'schemes'. 
They are then asked to enter a module name, which is saved to the hash, under the key which belongs to the scheme they just entered.

A line is then printed out telling the user that the scheme and the module have been added to the system.

They are then asked if they would like to add another module. This is where I have a couple of questions:

A. If the user types 'y', they are asked to enter the scheme- if the scheme they enter already exists, they are told, if not, it is created, and they are then asked for the module name. Then they are asked if they would like to add another module. If the user types 'n' the schemes that currently exist, along with their modules are printed out, and the program exits.

B. In this case, I had added two modules to the same scheme, but only the last one was printed out, so presumably, it is overriding the first one that was entered- how can I make sure that this doesn't happen, and that after the first module has been saved to the 'schemes' hash, any subsequent ones are appended to the end of the hash, and not replacing the one already there?

1. How can I make sure that the program doesn't exit when the user types 'n' at step A, but rather returns to the main program menu?
2. How can I make sure that the first piece of data saved to a hash is not overridden by any subsequent pieces of data that I save to the hash, but rather that they become separate entries? (The idea here being to have something similar to a Java ArrayList, that will automatically add the next bit of data to the next array element that is free- increasing numerically)

The two classes I have are Application (which is acting as my interface with the user), and CourseModules (which is where the data entered by the user is stored).

Application.rb currently looks like this:

```
class Application
# To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
require './courseModules.rb'
def initialize
  mainMenu
end

=begin
  def navigateTo(what)
    what.new(v).display
    mainMenu
  end
=end

  def mainMenu
    puts "What would you like to do?
      1: Add module to a scheme
      2: Remove module from a scheme
      3: Query modules
      4: Modify module
      5: Register a student on a scheme
      6: Remove a student from a scheme
      7: Register a student on a module
      8: Remove a student from a module"
    case gets.strip
      when "1"
        CourseModules.add_module
      when "2"
        CourseModules.removeModuleFromScheme
      when "3"
        navigateTo CourseModules
      when "4"
        navigateTo CourseModules
      when "5"
        navigateTo Student
      when "6"
        navigateTo Student
      when "7"
        navigateTo Student
    end
  end
  Application.new
end
```

and CourseModules.rb currently looks like this:

```
class CourseModules
# To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
@@moduleScheme = nil
@@moduleYear = nil
#@moduleTitle = ""
@noOfModulesInScheme = 0

def self.moduleYear
  @@moduleYear
end

def initialize(v)
  @val = v
end
# Set and get the @val object value
def set (v)
  @val = v
end
def get
  return @val
end


# Attempt at add_module method on 21/08/2012 at 12:35
def self.add_module
  schemes = {}
  scheme_exists = false
  add_another_module = true

 while add_another_module
   print "Enter scheme name: "
   scheme_name = gets
   schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false

   if !scheme_exists
     print "Enter module name: "
     module_name = gets
     schemes[scheme_name.chop] = module_name.chop
     puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} with module #{module_name} has been added to the system"
   else
     scheme_exists = false
     puts "This scheme has already been added"
     puts "Enter module name: "
     module_name = gets
     schemes[scheme_name.chop] = module_name.chop
     puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} with module #{module_name} has been added to the system"
   end

   print "Add another module? "
   ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module = gets
   if !(ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "yes")
     add_another_module = false
   end
 end
 puts schemes
 end




 end
 def removeModuleFromScheme
   moduleName.moduleScheme = nil
 end

 def queryModule

end
```

****Edit 21/08/2012 at 18:00*****

Ok, my courseModules class now looks like this:

```
class CourseModules
# To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
@@moduleScheme = nil
@@moduleYear = nil
#@moduleTitle = ""
@noOfModulesInScheme = 0

def self.moduleYear
 @@moduleYear
end

def initialize(v)
 @val = v
end
# Set and get the @val object value
def set (v)
 @val = v
end
def get
 return @val
end


# Attempt at add_module method on 21/08/2012 at 16:30
def self.add_module
 schemes = {}
 scheme_exists = false
 add_another_scheme = true
 add_another_module = true

 while add_another_scheme
   print "Enter scheme name: "
   scheme_name = gets
   @schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false

   if !scheme_exists
     @schemes[scheme_name.chop] = []
     puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} has been added to the system"
   else
     scheme_exists = false
     puts "This scheme has already been added"
   end

   while add_another_module
     print "Enter module name: "
     module_name = gets
     @schemes[scheme_name.chop].include?(module_name.chop) ? true : @schemes[scheme_name.chop] << module_name.chop
     print "Add another module? "
     ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module = gets
     if(!ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module == "yes")
      add_another_scheme = false
   end

 end

 print "Add another scheme? "
 ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme = gets
 if !(ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "yes")
   add_another_scheme = false
 end
 puts @schemes

end

 while add_another_module
   print "Enter scheme name: "
   scheme_name = gets
   schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false

   if !scheme_exists
     print "Enter module name: "
     module_name = gets
     schemes[scheme_name.chop] = module_name.chop
     puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} with module #{module_name} has been added to the system"
   else
     scheme_exists = false
     puts "This scheme has already been added"
     puts "Enter module name: "
     module_name = gets
     schemes[scheme_name.chop] = module_name.chop
     puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} with module #{module_name} has been added to the system"
   end

   print "Add another module? "
   ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module = gets
   if !(ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "yes")
     add_another_module = false
   end
 end
 puts schemes
end

end
```

but now, when I select '1' from the menu, and enter a scheme name, I'm getting an error on the line:

```
@schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false
```

which says

> in `add_module': undefined method`has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told you on the other thread if you need a 1:M relationship between scheme and modules you need to store modules in the array. Also you need to redefine schemes hash as an instance variable. i.e. in

```
def initialize
   @schemes = {}
   # ... your other code
end

def self.add_module
    scheme_exists = false
    add_another_scheme = true

    while add_another_scheme
        add_another_module = true 
        print "Enter scheme name: "
        scheme_name = gets
        @schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false

        if !scheme_exists
            @schemes[scheme_name.chop] = []
            puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} has been added to the system"
        else
            scheme_exists = false
            puts "This scheme has already been added"
        end

        while add_another_module
            print "Enter module name: "
            module_name = gets
            @schemes[scheme_name.chop].include?(module_name.chop) ? true : @schemes[scheme_name.chop] << module_name.chop
            print "Add another module? "
            ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module = gets
            if !(ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "yes")
               add_another_module = false
            end 
        end

        print "Add another scheme? "
        ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme = gets
        if !(ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "yes")
           add_another_scheme = false
        end
    end
    puts @schemes
end
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've been staring at this for so long now, I'm starting to miss things... I've changed the class to what you suggested, and tried running it, but I'm getting an error in the "while add_another_module part- it's complaining that there's a syntax error, enexpected ), expecting keyword_end...

Comment: well check again, must have messed something in copy paste, because as far as I see there is no syntax error and it works fine.

Comment: I've checked again, I deleted what was there, copied and pasted again, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Do I need to open braces after the close brackets or something? Or does Ruby not work in that way?

Comment: you have error here(i.e. after add_module method) - 

`end
 def removeModuleFromScheme
   moduleName.moduleScheme = nil
 end

 def queryModule

end`

Comment: it should be 

 `def removeModuleFromScheme
   moduleName.moduleScheme = nil
 end

 def queryModule

end
end`

Comment: Ahh, I think it was the ! was before the ( on line 50: "if(!ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module.chop == "y" or ask_if_user_wants_to_add_another_module == "yes")" 

The ! should have been after the (, not before as was suggested

Comment: Ok, the original problem now seems to be sorted- so many thanks for your help. I'm now having a another problem, which I wasn't getting earlier, so it seems that what I've done to fix the original problem has caused something else to stop working. I've updated my original post to show the new problem.